# HTML: href of anchor. How to concatenate instead of replace?

Tags: html

I am in the page

> www.myWebsite.com/registration?type=lookfor

And in the menu I have an anchor to change the language.

```
<a href="?lang=en">English</a>
```

If I click on this anchor, I will be redirect to

> www.myWebsite.com/registration?lang=en

... but the correct result would be

> www.myWebsite.com/registration?type=lookfor&lang=en

I could easily elaborate a javascript solution, but I would like to have a simple HTML solution, if there is any.

Comment: What do you do with the `lang` parameter if it is present?

Comment: Have you looked into how to use the `hreflang` attribute? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes Would that be helpful for your current needs?

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="?type=lookfor&lang=en">English</a>`
Try this html code for redirect with two query strings

Comment: It's not what I need. The parameter "type" is only for the page "registration".
Furthermore, the parameter 'type' can not be hardcoded, because there are two type of accounts for registration.

<a href="/registration?type=lookfor"></a>

<a href="/registration?type=nannie"></a>

And once I am in the page registration, I can choose the language. The language is in the main menu of the website. It must work in every page.

Comment: If you want to use lang in every page by setting one time
Then I think you need to use session
$_SESSION['lang']='en'
no need to pass in url(query string)